# how do I use linq to dataSet to convert dataTable to an array?

Tags: linq, dataset

I have the following sql table schema:

```
procudtId   productPrice  Color
==================================
1           3 $           Blue
1           3 $           Red
1           3 $           Green
2           5 $           Blue
2           5 $           Red
```

Using c# code I got this into dataSet.
How can I use linq to dataSet to build an array that looks like

```
[ price:"3$", ColorList:<"Blue","Red","Green"> ;
  price:"5$", ColorList:<"Blue","Red">]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
    //dt is the DataTable you're working with.
    var groups = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
                 group row["Color"] by row["productPrice"] into prices
                 select prices;

    var query = from g in groups
                select new
                {
                    price = g.Key,
                    ColorList = g.ToList()
                };
```

If that doesn't do it, let me know and I'll edit.

Comment: I'll check. Thanks. btw what is the linq translation to "group by + having" ? Is is like the way you wrote above: group row["Color"] by row["productPrice"] into prices?

Comment: Hope that helps. Basically, it groups all the row["Color"] values by row["productPrice"], so each price becomes a group, and each color for that price is placed in that group. [Here's some more info on LINQ's group clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384063.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I think I'll do this in two steps:

```
1. create the color lists
    var dataRows = from row in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                   //group row by row.Field<Int32>("TierId")
                   where row.Field<Int32>("ProductId") == 1
                   select
                       row.Field<String>("Color");

    List<String> list =  dataRows.ToList();

2. acquire the product price
3. combine them both to array
```